# Why is playing Minecraft on MX linux so smooth

Tags: debian, kernel, minecraft, mx-linux

Lately I've been trying to experiment with some linux distributions, then try to play games there such as minecraft.

I tried:

1. Manjaro - Lag
2. Drauger OS (It said for game) - Still lag
3. MX Linux - Really-really smooth

I could use MX Linux as the main distribution. However, because a lot of information says that some of the most Ubuntu packages can't run on MX Linux, I'm also hesitant to use it.

Can someone explain why minecraft is running so efficiently on MX Linux. Because I want to configure the same settings on Ubuntu to run smoothly like MX Linux. I think that this is a matter of drivers or kernel compatibiliy, but I'm not sure because there are many factors that determine linux performance.

Spec:

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye

Laptop   : Acer one Z 1402 (2016)
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHz
Graphics : Intel HD Graphics 5500
Kernel   : Linux 5.10.0-15-amd64 x86_64
RAM      : single Kingston sodimm 2GB 1600MHZ 
OpenGL   : 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.3.5
Minecraft: Minecraft launcher original. Version: 1.7.10-Forge10.13.4.1614-1.7.10
JVM Arg  : -Xmx512M -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -d64 -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
```

[image]

Rarely do I get 80 fps in minecraft 1.7.10 when using mod forge.

Comment: Isn't it a Windows game? If so, they all might have wildly different Wine versions, Wine staging patches applied or not. If it's a Java game, then JRE might be very different.

Comment: I am use bundled java version that located in same folder such .minecraft. I don't know how can MX Linux more efficient than Ubuntu while play minecraft, so this is why I asking.

Comment: Check their kernel configs for `CONFIG_HZ` `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL` and various `PREEMPT` options. Could also be down to the amount of RAM you have and background services.

Comment: I think it leans more towards processing instead of RAM

`CONFIG_HZ=250`

`# CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL is not set`

`# CONFIG_PREEMPT is not set`

Wait, what the special of this kernel configuration?